# Problem using impure function wrapped in pure function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, readfile

I'm trying to use the readFile function wrapped in a pure function.

Functions Used (In my school I have to re-write all built-in functions if I want to use it)

```
myNth :: [a] -> Int -> a
myNth [] n = error "error"
myNth (x:xs) 0 = x
myNth (_:xs) n = myNth xs (n - 1)
```

```
myTail :: [a] -> [a]
myTail (_:a) = a
myTail [] = error "empty list"
```

```
pointStrToInt :: String -> (Int, Int, Int)
pointStrToInt point = (read(myTail(myNth(split ',' point) 0)), read(myNth(split ',' point) 1), read(myNth(split ')' (myNth(split ',' point) 2)) 0))
```

```
fileToPointArray :: [String] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
fileToPointArray = map pointStrToInt
```

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split d [] = []
split d s = x : split d (drop 1 y) where (x,y) = span (/= d) s
```

Problem Function:

```
closest :: FilePath -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) 
closest path a = do
                    let content = readFile path
                    let closestPoint = pointStrToInt (myNth(lines (content)) 0)
                    --print (closestPoint)
                    let arr = fileToPointArray (lines content)
                    --print (arr)
                    let p = doClosest arr a closestPoint
                    --print (p)
                    p

    where
        doClosest :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
        doClosest [] _ a = a
        doClosest (x:xs) a (b, c, d) = if ((distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint a)) < (distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint (b, c, d))))
                                       then (doClosest xs a x)
                                       else (doClosest xs a (b, c, d))
```

The main objective is get the closest point to a given one passed as parameter.
The prototype must be something like:

```
closest :: FilePath -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
```

But I can't use a impure function (readFile) due to the function is not IO().

How could i fix it?

Edit:
-The file contains a set of points in (x,y,z) format

-The distance function return the distance of the 2 points

-The file can change in any execution

Comment: Can the external file be assumed to never change during the whole execution of the program? I.e., is it just a "large constant" that could be hard-coded in the program, but it's more convenient to keep it separated? If so, this might be one of the few cases where using unsafe functions might be acceptable. Otherwise, if that file changes, you have to be honest to the compiler and turn your function into an IO one, changing its type.

Comment: Why not just pass the file contents in as a parameter, and let the caller do the readFile? It will even do it lazily, so the actual IO work only gets done whenl you use the result.

Comment: Are the commented-out `print` statements in `closest` just for debugging? If so then you could use `Debug.Trace`, which is designed for that job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in a `do` bock; you just aren't taking advantage of it. `content` should be extracted *from* `readFile path`, not simply reference the `IO` action it creates. You'll also need to change the return value to `IO (Int, Int, Int)`:

```
closest :: FilePath -> (Int, Int, Int) -> IO (Int, Int, Int) 
closest path a = do
                    content <- readFile path
                    let closestPoint = pointStrToInt (myNth(lines (content)) 0)
                    let arr = fileToPointArray (lines content)
                    let p = doClosest arr a closestPoint
                    return p

    where
        doClosest :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
        doClosest [] _ a = a
        doClosest (x:xs) a (b, c, d) = if ((distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint a)) < (distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint (b, c, d))))
                                       then (doClosest xs a x)
                                       else (doClosest xs a (b, c, d))
```

A little simpler is to keep `closest` pure and combine it with `readFile` in a wrapper.

```
-- Note the order of arguments is reversed, so that we
-- can partially apply it later...
closest :: (Int, Int, Int) -> String -> (Int, Int, Int) 
closest content a = let closestPoint = pointStrToInt (myNth(lines (content)) 0)
                        arr = fileToPointArray (lines content)
                    in doClosest arr a closestPoint

    where
        doClosest :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
        doClosest [] _ a = a
        doClosest (x:xs) a (b, c, d) = if ((distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint a)) < (distance (itofPoint x) (itofPoint (b, c, d))))
                                       then (doClosest xs a x)
                                       else (doClosest xs a (b, c, d))

doIt :: FilePath -> (Int, Int, Int) -> IO (Int, Int, Int)
doIt path a = fmap (closest a) (readFile path)
```

(If you don't want to or can't alter the argument order in `closest`, you can use `fmap (flip closest a) (readFile path)` instead.)